# Simultaneous Controller function calls in ASP.net C# MVC

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm using AJAX to get a BASE64 png image that will then be displayed on the page.

However the size of this png image maybe quite large and so the transfer time may be long.

Also on the page there are other features that use AJAX.

The problem I have is that while I'm transfering the image the other AJAX functions will not run on the controller.

VIEW

```
function GetImage() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ImagesAnalysis/GetImage",
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (Data) {
           DrawImageOnCanvas(Data);
        } 
    return;
 }

function SearchFunction() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ImagesAnalysis/SearchFunction",
        datatype: "json",
        traditional: true,
        Data: SearchString,
        success: function (Data) {
           PutResultOnScreen(Data)
        } 
    return;
 }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public int GetImage()
{
    Return Image; //BASE64 IMage string may be LARGE!!!
}

public int SearchFunction(SearchString)
{
    Return DoSearchReturnResult(SearchString);
}
```

The Problem I have (using MVC5 ASP.NET IIS) is SearchFunction will not run until GetImage has completed sending the image to the view.

Is there any way to be able to run search function on the controller while GetImage is still returning the image

Comment: Is this in development? IIS Express (the web server built into Visual Studio) is single-threaded. That means it literally cannot handle more than one simultaneous request. This shouldn't be an issue in production.

Comment: Yes it is in development. I'll check out a production varient. Thanks a lot Chris

Comment: You just need full IIS. You could still run it locally if you want, just install IIS from Programs and Features on your machine, if you don't have it already, and deploy your site to wwwroot on your local machine.